# GUI apps uses registry,how?

Tags: executable, register

I have a GUI app that seems to use registry.
So I wanna know if I can capture that function that access registry and check if it's activated because this app doesn't use windows directory, it's just a click and a GUI pops pup.

Is it possible to identify how the app uses registry, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to dissect your executable in IDA Pro and find functions like these: *RegOpenKeyEx, RegSetValueEx, RegGetValue, RegQueryValueExW, RegCloseKey, RegOpenCurrentUser* (they are part of *advapi32.dll*).

If you prefer to analyse the registry activity of your app dynamically then use [regshot](http://sourceforge.net/projects/regshot/). It's very easy to use it - just make first shot of the registry before you launch your app and then second shot (after say 3-5 minutes) and then press *compare*-button. [regshot](http://sourceforge.net/projects/regshot/) will make a report about registry keys/values that have been opened, added, deleted.

Answer (score 2):

To see which registry keys your applications accesses while running, use [Procmon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx). If you want to monitor more DLL calls than mere registry accesses, i recommend [API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor).

Comment: Furthermore, both of those tools allow you to examine the call-stack for any captured log entry. That will help you find the function in your program that solicited the registry lookup.